# Creating a custom shape with sectors colored according to a numerical value in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a figure which consists of a custom grid with each sector colored according to a value. I'd also like to add symbols to show whether the value (effect estimate) is significant (* *p*<0.05)

This is the dummy data and the shape (the ratio of the 3 circle diameters is 1:3:6):

```
sectors <- c("upper_outer", "right_outer", "left_outer", "lower_outer", 
             "upper_inner", "lower_inner", "left_inner", "right_inner", "centre")
values <- sample(1:20, 9)
p_values <- seq(0.01, 0.09, by = 0.01)
df <- data.frame(sector = sectors, value = values, p_values = p_values)
```

[image: Custom shape]

Comment: Looks like a stacked bar plot with coord_polar  - https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/coord_polar.html or a circos plot - https://jokergoo.github.io/circlize_book/book/make-fun-of-the-package.html#a-dartboard.

Comment: You are looking for someone who implements the figure for you? In which format? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is just a bit of data wrangling and plotting with `geom_rect` in polar co-ordinates:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(sector = replace(sector, sector == 'centre', 'centre_centre')) %>%
  separate(sector, into = c('x', 'y')) %>%
  mutate(x = factor(x, c('upper', 'right', 'lower', 'left', 'centre')),
         y = factor(y, c('centre', 'inner', 'outer'))) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  reframe(xmin = c(0, 1, 2, 3, -Inf)[as.numeric(x)], 
          xmax = c(1, 2, 3, 4, Inf)[as.numeric(x)],
          ymin = c(0, 1, 3)[as.numeric(y)],
          ymax = c(1, 3, 6)[as.numeric(y)],
          value, p_values) |>
  ggplot(aes(xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax, ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax)) +
  geom_rect(aes(fill = value), data = . %>% filter(!is.finite(xmin))) +
  geom_rect(aes(fill = value), data = . %>% filter(is.finite(xmin)),
            color = 'black', linewidth = 1.5) +
  geom_text(aes(x = ifelse(is.finite(xmin), (xmin + xmax)/2, 2.5),
                y = (ymin + ymax)/2, 
                label = ifelse(p_values < 0.05, '**', '')),
                color = 'white', fontface = 2, size = 7) +
  coord_polar(start = -pi/4) +
  scale_fill_viridis_c() +
  theme_void()
```

[image]

Comment: This is a nicer solution

Answer (score 2):

You can do it as a bar chart plus polar coordinates:

```
library(ggplot2)

# test data mockup:
df <- data.frame(x= factor(rep(c("A","B","C","D"), each = 6)),
                 y = factor(rep(1:8, each = 3)),
                 freq = rep(seq(0, 1, length.out = 8), each = 3))


ggplot(df, aes(x=x, fill = y, alpha = freq)) + 
  geom_bar(width=1.0, color = "black") + 
  geom_bar(data = data.frame(x = factor(c("A","B","C","D"))), aes(x=x), width = 1.0, fill = "antiquewhite3", inherit.aes = FALSE) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 1, colour = "black") +
  coord_polar(theta = "x", start = pi/4)
```

The second `geom_bar` adds the central spot and the `geom_hline` makes a line above it which becomes a circle under the polar coordinates.

[image]